# Make Javascript a requirement

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to make Javascript a requirement to run pages on a website? such that if the user disables javascript, then he cannot proceed further? For example: I have a PHP site and would want to validate user-inputs with javascript only.

I apologise if this a trivial issue. I am quite new to javascript and i have never seen nor heard of such implementation, but it is solution i would love to know how to implement. Thanks.

Comment: You *cannot* use Javascript only to validate user inputs. Attackers can still forge requests with `curl`, DOM inspection tools, modifying Javascript, etc.

Comment: Not validating user inputs server-side is a dangerous game. You cannot trust anything coming from a client you can't control. No matter what protections you put in, a user could potentially make their own "browser" that completely ignores your client-side validation.

Comment: your form can be made to only show if they have js, but like other say, don't do that to avoid client side validation

Comment: Generally, people use the noscript tag to display alerts/whatever to people who have js disabled http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp But as the two commenters said above, in your use-case it might be dangerous to rely on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<noscript>` tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn’t support script.

The  element can be used in both  and .

You can do some thing like this below and redirect the users to some page saying please enable java script and try again by placing this below code in head tags

```
<noscript>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=showamessagewithjavascriptdisabled.html">
</noscript>
```

The above code in header will cause a refresh to URL specified if javascript is disabled

Comment: Doesn't seem to actually work (OS X/Chrome 28): [with noscript](http://jsfiddle.net/3RrZk/1/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/3RrZk/2/).

Comment: @Waleed Khan the way you are testing this is wrong you should create two pages in your local and one should have the noscript tag and other should have message and put that in your apache public html directory and load it via localhost

Comment: @Waleed Khan you are testing this in jsfiddle where javascript is enabled :)

Comment: What are the weaknesses of <noscript>? can a user bypass it's directives and continue with normal site use?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a PHP site and would want to validate user-inputs with
>   javascript only.

That is a realy bad idea, users can submit whatever evil data they want creating a html form and post it to your php files.

If you turn off JavaScript and watch this site you will see that some of the functions will work and some don't. You can display a message using the following code:

```
<div id="jsMessage">Please turn on JavaScript</div>
<script>document.getElementById("jsMessage").style.display="none";</script>
```

Comment: Or... use a `noscript` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the **NoScript** tag?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 0):

u can technically do that. I am guessing you can set up a cookie in js as soon as the page loads. And then check with php. If it exists, then js works, if not js is disabled. But don't forget that the user can change the cookie name/value manually. It is the same with every other client side control